# How do you implement an effective and secure function?

Tags: web-applications, security

I am encountering the problem: "Do I do too much in security?" or "Do I do too less security?"

First, I need to implement a "post message" function and an "edit message" function.

Here is a basic table structure:

`id, user_id, category_id, message_title, message_content`

these two methods seems very easy to implement, but when I think about the security, or hackers, I start worry...  Here is something I worry about:

About post a message:

> 1. Will the user submit a super long message in the database?
> 2. Will the user make SQL injection to break down my database?
> 3. Will the user keep post the message, and make my database full?
> 4. Will the user submit a invalid `category_id`? (for example, deleted or not yet appear or this user can't use that category)

About edit a message:

> 1. Will the user edit a message, which is not belong to him/her? (hack the `id`)
> 2. Will the user edit a message with a invalid `id`? (for example, deleted or not yet appear)
> 3. Will the user edit a SQL injection statement in my database?
> 4. Will the user edit a long message in the database?
> 5. Will the user edit a invalid `category_id`? (for example, deleted or not yet appear or this user can't use that category)

There are a few questions that I am concerned about. I can sort it into two types:

1. Technical security issue. (For example, SQL injection, the message length)
2. Programme logic issue. (For example, the `category_id` is not allow for that user)

I think that the technical security issues can be implemented using some standard library on the Internet, but the programme logic issues drive me crazy. Should I implement all the checking? For example, check that `category_id` is for that `user`, and check that `id` exists, etc. before I execute the related SQL cmd. It can be implemented, but it is very time consuming. Or do I just need to assume every input is valid, and a user won't hack a strange `category_id` in the system? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul C says, you should never trust your users. Or, rather, you should trust that your users will make every possible error in data entry, as well as a few malicious attempts to hack the database.

The time it takes to write the input validation will be a lot less than it will take to repair the problems in the database, and even then you'll still have to add the input validation to prevent similar problems. It's a lot easier to validate everything from the beginning.